# Dynamically update 2D configuration - Data from file

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I'm trying to simulate the evolution of a classical fluid in 2D. I have a file that contains the evolution of a configuration of points in a 2D, with a white line between each "snapshot". For 3 particles, something like :

x  y

1  4

2  2 <- snapshot at t

4  7

(white line)

2  2

4  5 <- snapshot at t+dt

1  9

(...)

Is it possible to get a dynamic plot in Mathematica showing this evolution? (Each point should be a circle of radius 0.5)

Comment: If you need assistance with importing and parsing your file, could you post a sample of the actual file?

Answer (score 1):

You can show the list of 2D snapshots on stacked planes in 3D as follows:

```
snapshots = RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {30, 3, 2}];
data = MapIndexed[Function[x, Append[x, 1 + 30 - #2[[1]]]] /@ # &, snapshots];

Manipulate[Graphics3D[{MapIndexed[{Opacity[(#2[[1]]/(t))^2], Red, 
      Scale[Sphere[#], {1, 1, 2/3}]} &, data[[;; t - 1]]],
  Opacity[1], Red, Scale[Sphere[#], {1, 1, 2/3}] & @ data[[t]],
  Opacity[.3, Blue], EdgeForm[Blue], 
  Polygon[{{-12, -12, 1 + 30 - t}, {12, -12, 1 + 30 - t}, 
     {12, 12,  1 + 30 - t}, {-12, 12, 1 + 30 - t}}]}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-12, 12}, {-12, 12}, {0, 32}}, 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 2}, 
  FaceGrids -> ({{{1, 0, 0}, {{}, #}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {{}, #}}, {{-1, 0,  0}, {{}, #}}, 
     {{0, -1, 0}, {{}, #}}} & @Table[2 + 30 - k, {k, 1, t - 1}]), 
  ImageSize -> Medium], 
{t, 1, 30, 1}]
```

[image]

Alternatively you can use `Animate` instead of `Manipulate`:

[image]